# Objective function for CP tensor decomposition

Tags: optimization, tensors, multilinear-algebra, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

What is the objective function for CP [(CANDECOMP/PARAFAC) tensor decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition)?

The decomposition tries to decompose a tensor $Z$ to $Z \approx \sum_{l=1}^L \lambda_l a_l \circ b_l \circ c_l $, where $\lambda_l \in \mathbb{R}_+$.   Does it mean that the objective function is squared error as in SVD? That is, is the corresponding optimization problem as below

$$\min_{\lambda,a,b,c: \|a_l\|=\|b_l\|=\|c_l\|=1, \lambda_l \ge 0} \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k (Z_{ijk} -\sum_{l=1}^L \lambda_l a_{li} \circ b_{lj} \circ c_{lk} )^2$$

Typically the objective is the squared $L_2$ distance for decomposition, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_l$,  $b_l$, and  $c_l$ should be replaced by $a_{li}$, $b_{lj}$, and  $c_{lk}$, respectively. The norm constraints  and $\lambda$ in min  and cost function can be dropped, i.e., $\min\limits_{a_k,b_k,c_k}$ is okay (unconstrained optimization). There are several matlab tooklboxes  that compute CP decomposition (e.g., tensorlab.net)

Comment: I can see now that my indices is messed up. I will fix it. Thanks for mentioning it! How is it that the constraints can be dropped? Does it not mess up the uniqueness of decomposition? Would you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: One more thing:  I suppose that $\lambda$-s are not known. In this case $\lambda$-s  should also be under $\min$.

Comment: @ Ignat. Fixed! Thanks! So the constraints would be okay?

Comment: $\lambda $ and the norm constraints in min can be dropped because $\lambda$ can be moved inside $a\circ b\circ c$, e.g. $(\lambda a)\circ b\circ c$. In other words, $a$, $b$, $c$ can be recovered only up to scalars $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha\beta\gamma=1$ (indeed, $a\circ b\circ c=\alpha a\circ \beta b \circ \gamma c$)

Comment: Uniqueness of CP decomposition means uniqueness up to  permutation of rank-$1$ terms, so moving constants in/out rank-$1$ terms does not affect uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

The article you link to is also titled [Tensor Rank Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition):

> [T]he tensor rank decomposition is sometimes historically referred to as PARAFAC or CANDECOMP.
>
> When the number of terms $r$ is minimal in the above expression, then $r$ is called the **rank** of the tensor, and the decomposition is often referred to as a (tensor) rank decomposition, minimal CP decomposition, or Canonical Polyadic Decomposition (CPD).

The objective function for an (exact) decomposition as a sum of rank one tensors is not about an approximating sum, but rather about *minimizing* how many rank one tensors are needed to give an exact summation.  Thus the objective function here is a *discrete* function, counting the number of terms used.

Of course $n^2$ such tensors always suffice for an $n\times n$ matrix (or indeed $n$ will suffice), but in the "tensor rank" problem we want to know how *few* will suffice.

Comment: I see. So you are saying that since the decomposition is exact the recovery error is zero, and  it does not matter with which norm we measure it. It still remains zero.  Then the question  would be how about a rank "L" CP, for a fixed rank $L$. Then the decomposition would not be exact, right. I am wondering if we have such a thing, such as in SVD?

Comment: @user25004  Such a thing called higher-order SVD. But it is quite  different from the CP decomposition. The optimization problem in your question may not have a solution (so called divergent components)

Comment: Yes, you can certainly pose the problem, for various matrix or tensor norms, asking the "best approximation" by a sum of fixed $k \lt r $ rank one tensors.  The SVD answers one version of this for matrices.

Comment: @Ignat Are you saying the CP decomposition is always considered an  exact decomposition? And if we need up to a  number $K$, we need to go for higher-order SVD instead of CP? This would imply that the choice of the objective would not matter at all then? Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: No, CP decomposition and Higher-order SVD are two different decompositions (so the cost functions are also different).

Comment: Uniqueness makes sense only for the exact CP decomposition. If you start from the exact CP decomposition and add noise, then the rank of the noisy tensor significantly increases (typical rank), so you can consider only approximation by a rank-L decomposition. To my knowledge, there are no results on uniqueness of the approximation, but  in practice, one of course computes it with a hope  that if a tensor had a unique (exact) decomposition,  and if the noise was sufficiently small, then the rank-L approximation will be close to the actual "true" CP-decomposition.